# Tmux style tab switching in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, viml

I am looking for a way to map number keys to :tabnext in VimL.
I want to make it easier when switching tabs and enable  tmux style switching.

```
map <leader>t[0-9] :tabnext regex([0-9])
```

This is my working solution but I not sure if there is any facility for regex in Vim.
Is it possible to map a range of keys, to a regular expression?

Comment: What if you are using vim within tmux?

Comment: The leader key is defined as " , " to avoid this.

Comment: Why a mapping when you can do `4gt`?

Comment: Do you mind a giving a quick explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to achieve this. Add to your *.vimrc* :

```
for i in range(9)
  execute printf('nnoremap <silent> <leader>t%d :tabnext %d<CR>', i, i)
endfor
```